# Bulk Updating Woocommerce Variation Prices

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update woocommerce variation prices with a php/mysql script outside of wordpress.

I have a script that updates the `_price` and `_regular_price` value of one `product_variation` of a `product` in `wp_postmeta` table.

If I have ***more than one*** variation the correct price of the variation is displayed on the webpage - but the the price / price range coming from woocommerce`s price.php is not updated.

However, if I have ***only this one*** variation, the price in the table is updated, but not at all on the rendered webpage.

I also tried to edit the prices of the `product` itself. But: I still get the old price on the rendered webpage.

Basically I now have the same new price in these fields:

in *product-variation -> postmeta*: `_price, _regular_price`

and in  *product -> postmeta*:    `_price, _regular_price, _min_variation_price, _max_variation_price, _min_variation_regular_price, _max_variation_regular_price`

I couldn't find any other fields with a price - I'm stuck...

Did I miss anything? Is there any other table/field to be updated?

Thanks for your help!

-EDIT-

Maybe this helps: Apparently when having only one Variation my price is rendered with `echo $product->get_price_html();` instead of `echo $value['price_html'];`. So where is the price used in `$product->get_price_html();` stored?

Comment: A variable product's price's are determined during the [`sync()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/e552c3c916e46c25fabd1937b1466d00d7925997/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L726) method. If you change a variation's price programmatically, you will also need to re-sync the variable product's prices.

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking, unfortunately my script is outside of wordpress. Can I add a filter in my functions.php for that or something? Like hook into `woocommerce_get_price_html`? If yes, can you give me a hint how to trigger the sync? I'm not good with wordpress hooks and filters... Thanks!

Comment: @helgatheviking I've dug a little deeper today and found out that including `wp-load.php`should be sufficient to use woocommerce hooks. I tried simply calling `do_action( 'woocommerce_variable_product_sync', $productId] );` but it wouldn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK after some digging around and thanks to @helgatheviking who pointed me in the right direction I tried this:

1. included wp-load.php in script
2. called `WC_Product_Variable::sync( $post_id );`

-> unfortunately this didn't work for me. I just put it here because I think this is the right approach - hopefully it helps someone else.

What actually helped me was including this in my functions.php:

```
// Display Price For Variable Product With Same Variations Prices
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', function ($value, $object = null, $variation = null) {
    if ($value['price_html'] == '') {
        $value['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>';
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 3);

// Hook into price html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price, $product ){
    WC_Product_Variable::sync( $product->id );
    $myPrice = $product->min_variation_price;
    $priceFormat = str_replace(utf8_encode('.'), ",", $myPrice);
    return '<span class="amount">from ' . $priceFormat . ' €</span>';
}
```

Comment: The above didn't work for you because you also need to delete the transient `"wc_var_prices_$product_id"` which is used for some displays.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following script to bulk update the product variations.
Click here for full code. https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/bulk-update-product-variation-price-woocommerce/

```
function getExistingProducts($updatedPrices,$skuArray) {

$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 'posts_per_page' => -1));

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    $id = get_the_ID();
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $sku = get_post_meta($id, '_sku', true);

    if( in_array( $sku, $skuArray  ) ) {

        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $attributes['medium-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][4];
        $attributes['low-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][3];
     $attributes['v-low-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][2];
        update_post_meta( $id,'_product_attributes',$attributes);
        echo ' Update Sku : '.$sku.' '.PHP_EOL;

    }

endwhile;

}
```